# "Best way" to run Laravel queue listen

Tags: laravel, queue, listener

Currently I'm working on a project where I queue emails to be send. However I wonder what would be the "best way" to run the queue listener. Right now I only know about the `nohup` way.

However, by using `nohup` it feels like the queue listener is no part of the application anymore. It's like using the scheduler to make your cronjobs more part of the application.

Are there any other ways to listen the queue and what would be your preference?

Comment: I achieved this by writing a process listener type task that I scheduled to run every minute. What that does is check to see if the queue is running using `pgrep`, and starts it if it finds that it isn't running.

Comment: @Jonathon A task like in cronjob? I also had this idea in my head by adding `queue:listen` to my laravel schedule to run every day but adding `withoutOverlapping()`. It would like look: `$schedule->command('queue:listen')->daily()->withoutOverlapping();`.

Comment: Yeah I created the console command `App\Console\Commands\QueueProcessListener`. I then added it to the `Kernel.php` to make it available to Artisan and I eventually added it to the Kernel's `schedule` method to get it to run every 5 minutes: `$schedule->command('queue-process-listener')->everyFiveMinutes();`

Comment: See my answer for how I achieved it

Comment: An alternative to monitoring the queue is using https://eyewitness.io - that will alert you if a queue stops for any reason (disclaimer: my site)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I wrote to achieve this:

**app/Console/Commands/QueueProcessListener.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class QueueProcessListener extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name of the command/process we want to monitor. This string will be used both to check to see if the process
     * is currently running and to spawn it (The arguments are appended to it).
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $command = 'php artisan queue:listen';

    /**
     * The arguments to pass to the process when spawning it.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $arguments = '--tries=3';

    /**
     * The signature of the console command. We use the signature when running it through Artisan: php artisan $signature
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'queue-process-listener';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Monitor the queue listener process to ensure it is always running.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if (!$this->isProcessRunning($this->command)) {
            $this->info("Starting queue listener.");
            $this->executeShellCommand($this->command, $this->arguments, true);
        } else {
            $this->info("Queue listener is running.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute a shell command, with the provided arguments, and optionally in the background. Commands that are not run
     * in the background will return their output/response.
     *
     * @param $command
     * @param string $arguments
     * @param bool $background
     * @return string
     */
    public function executeShellCommand($command, $arguments = '', $background = false)
    {
        $command = trim($command);
        if (!is_string($command) || empty($command)) {
            return null;
        }

        $arguments = trim($arguments);

        $cmd = trim($command . ' ' . $arguments) . ($background ? ' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &' : '');
        return shell_exec($cmd);
    }

    /**
     * Check if a process is running using pgrep.
     *
     * @param $process
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isProcessRunning($process)
    {
        $output = $this->executeShellCommand('pgrep -f "' . $process . '"');

        return !empty(trim($output));
    }
}
```

**app/Console/Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\QueueProcessListener::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         // Schedule my process listener to run every 5 minutes.
         $schedule->command('queue-process-listener')->everyFiveMinutes();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will do it like you said. Isn't `$schedule->command('queue:listen')->daily()->withoutOverlapp‌​ing()` not enough? Since it is already a command that can be called and executed.

Comment: Cool. The problem with doing that is that if the queue listener for some reason stops during the day, it won't start up again until the next day. On the flip side if it doesn't stop during the day, you run the risk of having multiple queue listeners running (If you start the command in the background using `nohup` or `&` etc.). If you're running the `queue:listen` command directly, it won't finish executing in time to let other commands you've scheduled run too - so you would effectively block the scheduler up.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Forget the `daily()` or `everyMinute()`. By using `withoutOverlapp‌​‌​ing()` you prevent it from being executed while still running, right? Or are you saying the scheduler will queue/stack these commands even if `withoutOverlapp‌​‌​ing()` is used to be executed after previous is done? And also are you saying the scheduler is not async (it cannot execute more than one at a time)?

Comment: Yeah, `withoutOverlapping()` will stop commands in the scheduler from overlapping with each other, rather than the command `php artisan queue:listen` under the hood. If your scheduled job ends up executing `php artisan queue:listen &` (Or using `nohup`) then the scheduled job will finish fine. But the next time the command is scheduled to run, it will spawn a new instance of `php artisan queue:listen &`. Without overlapping only stops the Laravel commands from overlapping, not the process it has spawned. On the other hand, if you start the command synchronously and end up running...

Comment: ... `php artisan queue:listen`. Then the command will never finish and the scheduler will never get to execute the next job. I *think* the scheduler will run synchronously in that every minute it checks for jobs it needs to run and fires them off one after the other, before it terminates. I'm not sure if it spawns separate processes to execute each scheduled job.

Comment: Ah now it makes sence to me :) Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122902/discussion-between-thomas-van-der-veen-and-jonathon).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you exactly how to achieve this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#supervisor-configuration

I'm not sure what you mean by it not being "part of the application".  Crons and background worker processes are a standard part of any scale server architecture.  There's nothing wrong with using them.

You also should really avoid doing what Jonathon's answer suggests, which is basically writing your own `supervisord` in php.  What if your server reboots?  There are battle-tested solutions for this problem, that have been developed and supported by the linux community for a long time now--you should really use them.